# linux AWK command to with operarion

Tags: linux, shell

i get below result on Linux awk command, 
,i want to grep all with greater than  this filed  [360] . the filed name is $13

```
[4]
[440]
[360]
[3]
[434]
[3]
[439]
[590]
```

the result should be  :

```
[440]
[434]
[439]
[590]
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with awk:

```
awk '{a=$0;gsub("[\\[\\]]","",$13);if(int($13)>360) {print a;}}' filename
```

it will print all lines, that action processed with greater than 360 mills.

Comment: iam get below error  when run above command : awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: What is delimiter in file?

Comment: the delimiter is [ , iam checking it , i will come back to you , if it will not run .

Comment: Add input file's at least one full line

Comment: 2012-06-12 13:59:23,471 QQ  [commit] AA=[1234567300499] BB=[9202910] Id=[8930261] AId=[125074001] Status=[340]  Action processed in [590] millis.

Comment: above is the line that i get it in my file , simply i want to get , all lines that  Action processed  with greater than 360 mills.

Comment: edited and now it will print full lines, not only 13th field. but please add full error. it must work.

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: strange. what os are you using? try use gawk

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  '!/\[3..\]|\[.\]/' file

[440]
[434]
[439]
[590]
```

Not to print three hundred... or one unit.